# Rotate animation not working in android 4.0

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In my Android application, I apply programmatically a rotation animation to a drawable object :

```
    Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.rotate);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.progress).startAnimation(rotation);
```

This is working fine in Android 2.3, but fails in 4.0. The drawable is not animated in 4.0.
What could be the problem here ?

**EDIT**
Here is my `rotate.xml` file :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" 
        android:duration="2000"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved the code just before the call of the `show` method of the container view and it's working now, both in 2.3 and 4.0 :

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainView.this, R.animator.rotate);
progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.progress).startAnimation(rotation);
progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: view.setAnimation(anim) does  work in android 2.2 and 2.3 but not android 4.0 and above device so use view.startAnimation(anim);